# Scope of C++ ComPtr Callback

Tags: c++, asynchronous, callback, wrl

I have been reading up on WRL, specifically using Callback and ComPtr to effect an asynchronous operation. However I cannot seem to get a clear answer on the lifetime of ComPtr when used in this way. The Callback utilizes information that the async function returns, but does not rely on any other information from the application, so I would like to not wait for its completion. For example:

```
void SomeFunction()
{
  ComPtr<IAsyncOperation<...*>> pOperation;

  //Activate instance and call async function

  pOperation->put_Completed(Callback<IAsyncOperationCompletedHander<...*>[...](...)
  {
    //Logic to be completed when Async call finishes
  }).Get());

  //Function exits here, process keeps running. Is pOperation going to get cleaned up?
}
```

I am under the impression that since ComPtr is a smart pointer, it won't get garbage collected until the callback completes and the refcount == 0, is this correct?

Comment: No, its scope is the body of the function here, just like any smart pointer type works in C++.  It is dead by the time the callback runs.  Neither WRL nor ComPtr<> are exactly very convenient when you have to deal with callbacks, the C++/CX extension makes it easier.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-in-cpp-universal-windows-platform-apps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. pOperation is dead by the time the callback runs, but the callback will still execute?